# 301 htaccess Rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect:

```
http://www.website.com/second/prefix-whatever.php
```

To:

```
http://www.website.com/prefix-whatever.php
```

`prefix` is constant, but `whatever.php` has multiple variations, I wish to avoid a couple of hundred lines in the htaccess file but I'm not sure how to do pattern matching.

Could somebody please help or direct me to a solution if they know of one that has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^second/(prefix-.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301.NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That appears to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Redirect 301 ^/second/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1
```

Comment: This will redirect all in the `second` folder to the home folder. For ex.: `/second/style.css` -> `/style.css` and this is not the expected result, I think.

Comment: Thank you both, yes, I only want to redirect files in the second folder that have file names beginning "prefix".  Sorry if I was not clear on that.